# How to share data between steps in Cucumber feature file?

Tags: java, test-automation-framework, cucumber, rest-assured

I am designing automation scripts using the REST APIs, RestAssured with Cucumber BDD framework. I have multiple APIs where one API's response is used as a parameter in another API.
Here is my feature file:

```
Feature: Create Order API

  @Background:
  Scenario Outline: Generate Access token With Valid Details
    Given Query param for request
      | grant_type         |
      | client_credentials |
    Given Basic Auth keys for request "<userName>" and "<key>"
    When Build request for baseurl "PAYPAL_BASE_URI" and endpoint "ENDPOINT_GET_AUTH_KEY"
    And Perform "POST" request using
    Then status code is 200
    And  response contains "scope"
    Examples:
      | userName | key        |
      | AWnCb    | EMAekuSA2f |
```

Now the response of the above API is as follows:

```
{
    "scope": "https://uri.pppaypal.com/services/invoicing https://uri.pppaypal.com/services/applications/webhooks",
    "access_token": "ALs1szFnv2TJ19Zf3vq",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "app_id": "APP-284543T",
    "expires_in": 311286,
    "nonce": "2022-05-31T03:41:41ZWs9dpOQ"
}
```

Now I need this "access_token" as in the "Create Order API" Authorization parameter with Bearer. also i need to pass "app_id" and "nonce" in the Create Order API.   The "Create Order API" feature file is below:

```
  Scenario: Verify create order api using valid auth
    Given Generate request
    And Build request for baseurl "PAYPAL_BASE_URI" and endpoint "ENDPOINT_CREATE_ORDER_API"
    And Set header values as
      | Content-Type     | Authorization | app_id   | nonce   |
      | application/json | <token>       | <app_id> | <nonce> |
    When Perform "POST" request using "FILE_PATH_ORDER_JSON"
    Then status code is 201
```

How can I get the values from the response of one API and the use that data in the next API as payload or query param in the same feature file so that I can use it anywhere in this feature file?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you will be using the same access token for all scenarios, the simplest way is to have a [Singleton](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton) that holds the data.

```
class AccessData {

   public static String accessToken;
   public static String ....
   
   private AccessData() {}

}
```

Then, on the Background scenario, you should do `AccessData.accessToken = blablabla`. In the scenario itself, you can retrieve the data `AccessData.accessToken`.

If you want to have access data for multiple users (userName in the Background scenario), you can have a Singleton that holds a map from a user name to an AccessData object.

```
class AccessData {

   private static HashMap<String, UserDataAccess> usersData = new HashMap();
   
   private AccessData() {}

   public void setAccessData(String userName, UserDataAccess userDataAccess) {
     // here you set the new entry on the map
   }

   public void getAccessData(String userName) {
     return usersData.get(userName);
   }

}

class UserDataAccess { // This is a simple data class; from Java 17 onwards you can Records

   public String accessToken;
   public String ....
}
```

Comment: Background scenario would also be written in Cucumber feature file only. Java logic can not be applied to feature files. It won't recognise anything except step definition. I am still not getting how would i pass the access token and other parameters in the next API in same feature file.